# Allow an animation to finish before starting a new activity

Tags: android, animation

I would like to perform an animation on an image before switching to a new activity. I also want to make sure that the animation is fully completed before the new activity starts. Below is the code that I am using to accomplish the task.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ViewReadingActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
        imgAries.startAnimation(shake);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewReadingActivity.this, ShowHoroActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

The problem with this is that the animation does not run to completion before the new activity is presented and the animation will continue to run from where it was left. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: have you try my answer?

Comment: Yes. I have and it works. The transition to the new activity is a bit slow this way though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use like this here you can have animation listner

```
shake.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(ViewReadingActivity.this, ShowHoroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sanket. This really is what I am looking for. You need to apply the method on shake though becuase shake is the animation object not imgAries.

Comment: You need to wait a set period of time before you can accept it, Sanket. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

do this:
 1.  animation.setAnimationListener(), implement the methods
 2. onanimationend method , write in the code to start a new activity

m late :(

Answer (score 1):

Animation Listener Already Contains the Method called as onAnimationEnd @override it on your
imgAries Animation Listener

```
onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
//Start you Activity here using Intent
Intent i=new Intent(this,//Your next Activity);
startActivity(i);

 }
```

That it...Now you can go to Next Activity on Animation End...Thks